# Tail-recursive program in prolog which outputs odd numbers in a list

Tags: prolog, tail-recursion

I've written a tail-recursive predicate in Prolog which outputs the integers between `A` and `B` in a list `K`. I've used "reverse" to bring the numbers into the right order:

```
numbers(A,B,K) :- numbers(A,B,[],K).
numbers(Y,Y,X,K) :- !, reverse([Y|X],K).
numbers(A,B,X,K) :- A<B, C is A+1, numbers(C,B,[A|X],K).
```

Query:

```
?- numbers(3,6, K).
   K=[3,4,5,6]
```

All works fine. What I now want to do is that I only want to have odd numbers of the range between `A` and `B` in the list `K`. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would try to avoid using `reverse/2`. If you have such a solution, it's often an indicator that there's a better way to get the answer forwards more directly. Not always, but most often. `reverse/2` is probably the 2nd favorite band-aid in Prolog right behind use of the cut. :)

In many problems, an auxiliary accumulator is needed. In this particular case, it is not. Also, I would tend to use CLP(FD) operations when involving integers since it's the more relational approach to reasoning over integers. But you can use the solution below with `is/2`, etc, if you wish. It just won't be as general.

```
numbers(S, E, []) :- S #> E.   % null case
numbers(X, X, [X]).
numbers(S, E, [S|T]) :-
    S #< E,
    S1 #= S + 1,
    numbers(S1, E, T).

| ?- numbers(3, 8, L).

L = [3,4,5,6,7,8] ? ;

no
| ?- numbers(A, B, [2,3,4,5]).

A = 2
B = 5 ? ;

no
| ?-
```

This solution avoids `reverse/2` and is tail recursive.

To update it for odd integers, the first thought is that we can easily modify the above to do every other number by just adding 2 instead of 1:

```
every_other_number(S, E, []) :- S #> E.
every_other_number(X, X, [X]).
every_other_number(S, E, [S|T]) :-
    S #< E,
    S1 #= S + 2,
    every_other_number(S1, E, T).

| ?- every_other_number(3, 7, L).

L = [3,5,7] ? ;

no
| ?- every_other_number(3, 8, L).

L = [3,5,7] ? ;

no
| ?- every_other_number(4, 8, L).

L = [4,6,8] ? ;

no
| ?-
```

Then we can do odd numbers by creating an initial predicate to ensure the condition that the first value is odd and calling `every_other_number/3`:

```
odd_numbers(S, E, L) :-
    S rem 2 #= 1,
    every_other_number(S, E, L).
odd_numbers(S, E, L) :-
    S rem 2 #= 0,
    S1 #= S + 1,
    every_other_number(S1, E, L).

| ?- odd_numbers(2, 8, L).

L = [3,5,7] ? ;

no
| ?- odd_numbers(2, 9, L).

L = [3,5,7,9] ? ;

no
| ?- odd_numbers(3, 8, L).

L = [3,5,7] ? ;

no
| ?-
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your solution and the solution of @damianodamiano are both very good in my opinion! Again, Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This could be a solution, using `mod/2` operator.

```
numbers(A,B,K) :- 
    B1 is B+1,
    numbers(A,B1,[],K).
numbers(Y,Y1,X,K) :- 
    Y = Y1,
    reverse(X,K).
numbers(A,B,X,K) :- 
    A<B, 
    C is A+1,
    C1 is mod(C,2),
    (C1 = 0 ->  
        numbers(C,B,[A|X],K)
    ; numbers(C,B,X,K)).
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use DCG :

```
numbers(A,B,K) :-
    phrase(odd(A,B), K).

odd(A,B) --> {A > B, !}, [].

odd(A,B) --> {A mod2 =:= 0, !, C is A+1}, odd(C,B).
odd(A,B) --> {C is A+2}, [A], odd(C, B).
```